# Searching for files with a specific pattern

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex, glob

I'm trying to look for specific files in a directory using a pattern

Lets say i have the id of the user - 101

here are my files

```
101
101_2
101_5
10111
103
10125
101_6
```

I'm trying to form a regex pattern which only gives me files (101,101_2,101_5,101_6)

I'm trying the below pattern

```
^101_?\d+$
```

but it doesnt seem to pick any of the files at all. if i remove the `^`.only `101_6` matches for some reason.

EDIT:

I'm using rails/ruby to look for files in the particular directory. so something like

```
Dir.glob(location).grep("^101_?\d+$")
 do something
end
```

Comment: Can you show how do you use regex to find files?

Comment: Try replacing `+` in `^101_?\d+$` by `*`.

Comment: If you're using `Dir.glob`, that's a glob, not a regex.

Comment: @Samadi - ur right , i ll be adding the location there and grep it with regex. at least thats what i hope would work

Comment: I'd simply use the glob `101_?` and then check that the last character is a digit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question isn't particularly clear, but I'm guessing you want to match anything which is `101` followed by an optional underscore and a digit. If so, use the regex `^101_?\d$`. If you want `101` followed by either a digit or an underscore and one or more digits, use `^101(_\d+|\d)$`

**EDIT**

As the OP has mentioned in a comment, `101` should also be matched. The updated regex is `^101(?:_?\d)?$`

Comment: i'm also trying to capture a 101 file (no underscore) . but then , it also seems to capturing files like 101124 or 1011 etc

Comment: @Kunkka, use `^101(?:_?\d)?$` instead. Your one will match `101_`

Comment: @CarySwoveland, yes. That's been corrected in a comment. I'll make an edit now.

Answer (score 1):

If `location` isn't the current folder, paths returned by `glob` will contain dirname and basename :

```
Dir.glob('./*').select{ |f| File.basename(f) =~ /\A101(_\d+)?\z/ }.each do |f|
  puts f
  # do something with f
end
```